# newViewController always with two nibs (iPhone & iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Customize xcode for universal apps xibs, so that when i create a new ViewController like VideoVC, it must create two nib files for that like,

- VideoVC_iPhone
- VideoVC_iPad

Can some one help me out. no guidelines. just the steps. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see the templates folder inside "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode"
here you will see file and project templates that you can edit or make a new one if you want to.

Specific to your question, navigate to this folder "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates"

Here you can achieve what you are trying to do by adding a blank nib for iPad with in the template for view controller with nib. I have upload a sample i did, it's still a work in progress but it will create 2 nibs as you need.

```
[my custom template]
http://www.saplogix.net/Xcode_Custom_Template/TwoNibTemplate.zip
extract and copy that inside this folder "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates"

Note: create the directory if it's not already there.
```

Todo: add code to load specific nib based on device which is also done just need to add that. Also it will only work for UIViewController as super class.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    }
    else
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            NSString *_nibBundleOrNil = (NSString *)(nibBundleOrNil != nil ? [nibNameOrNil stringByAppendingString:@"_iPad"] : [NSStringFromClass([self class]) stringByAppendingString:@"_iPad"]);
            self = [super initWithNibName:_nibBundleOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        }
    
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

My template will produce the following entry u can use that to create controller with 2 nibs.
[image: My template will produce the following entry u can use that to create controller with 2 nibs.]

Comment: I am creating an open source Google Project for this and will upload i have done and future work that i will do regarding this, if you have any other templates in mind do let me know. [Google Project - Xcode Custom Templates](http://code.google.com/p/xcode-custom-templates/)

Comment: Don't add files to your Xcode folder - when you upgrade Xcode, you'll lose your changes. The correct location for custom templates is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/`. You'll need to create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Abizern thank you for pointing that out, i have updated the path in my answer.

Comment: @SAPLogix This option is not available in Xcode 4.6 or higher. How to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom view controller template to do this. It's easier to create a new file template than it is to create a new project template, so it's perfectly possible to do.

I gave a presentation an this a while ago - [the slides](http://lanyrd.com/2011/lidg28/sffpf/) might be useful.

Comment: can you send me the slides link with me

Comment: I've added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a viewcontroller with following naming convention ,either create iphone/ipad xib as `"viewcontrollername~iPhone.xib"` or `@"viewcontrollername~iPad.xib"`

and below link states the same , provides way to differentiate ipad and iphone in your viewcontroller.h and viewcontroller.m

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.de/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

Comment: but this doesn't to create template, one XIB for iphone and another for ipad

Answer (score -3):

When you're creating your new Xcode project, select Single View Application, on the options page, in the Devices drop down, select Universal. This will create both iPhone and iPad nibs.

From start to finish:

File -> New Project

Select Single View Application -> Next

Devices -> Universal

Comment: it only create for the first time. how to create the 2nd time or more